# C# Adding Combobox dynamically losing selected items in others Combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

On a form, I have a default ComboBox, I have another button that allows user to add more ComboBoxes, however, when user adds new combobox dynamically, existing selected value in the default combo box changes, where as idea is however many ComboBoxes are added, every previously added ComboBox would not lose a selection if user has selected anything.
Can some one point in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Only your code can tell the tale, good if you can have it here.

Comment: One reason can be that both comboboxes are bind to the same source.

Comment: It's because page reloading. you have to do something about that

Answer (score 0):

You are not very clear on your problem, however I would suggest setting a new `BindingContext` to your Control, before adding it to the form.
Good luck.